# How to tail HDFS file with Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, logstash, spark-streaming

I am using HDFS to store raw JSON lines:

```
/user/ebuildy/logs/today.json

{"event":"buy", "tag1" : "20€", "tag2" : "user2"}
...
```

With Elastic Logstash, webhdfs output plugin (meaning JSON lines are appended into today.json every X seconds).

An other side, I am using Apache SparkSQL to query the data. Loading data is working like a charm:

```
CREATE TABLE events USING org.apache.spark.sql.json OPTIONS (path "hdfs://hadoop:9000/user/ebuildy/logs/today.json")
```

And I can query it with Tableau very easily (btw great job guys!).

Now, what I try to achieve as best as I can is to append incoming data into Spark (as well than HDFS file).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This about it this way: Your Table is nothing but a wrapper (with schema and LOTS of goodies) around RDD which got created by that load command, which read the data from HDFS and created RDD partitions.

Now, RDD is immutable. So, appending new data means (old RDD + new Data) -> new RDD.

You have various options, but it really depends on you use case. Given you want to connect with Tableau, so may be you are looking to create an ETL kind of workload which may run every 30 mins or so? If so, you may want to manage reading files from HDFS every run and do an union with existing RDD, create a new RDD and then switch the existing RDD with the new one.

Comment: Hello Ayan, since file can be very big, is it possible to load only new portion rather than all the file?